# Valid Text File Integer Input - C++

Tags: c++, cmd

I'm currently trying to do an error check within the while loop, that outputs an error message if the value within the text file is limited between 0-15

Examples of valid number input: 6 0 15 9 12

Examples of invalid number input: 16 -4 8.54 8v +6 127 b u7

I'm not completely sure on how to do an error check if there's an invalid number input within the txt file

````
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        // no parameters on command line just the program name

        cout << "3719632,s3719632@student.rmit.edu.au,Neshant_Thiru" << endl;

        // The convention is to return Zero to signal NO ERRORS, if you change it the AutoTester will
        //assume you have made some major error.  Leave it as zero.
        return 0;
    }


    //--- START YOUR CODE HERE - After you have modified the above cout statement with your details.
    if (argc == 2) {
        string line_;
        ifstream file_(argv[1]);

        unsigned int var;
        int a = 240;
        unsigned int b;

        if (file_.is_open())
        {
            while (file_ >> var)
            {


                if (var >= 0 && var <= 15) {

                    b = a + var;
                    WritePortB(b);
                    cout << toBinary(b) << endl;
                    cout << '\n';
                    Sleep(1000);

                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Y" << endl;
                    cout << '\n';
                }
            }
            file_.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "F" << endl;
        }

    }
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        cout << "P" << endl;
    }

        // The convention is to return Zero to signal NO ERRORS, if you change it the AutoTester will
        //assume you have made some major error.  Leave it as zero.
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: Exuse me, what's your question?

Comment: Is this currently not working as you ave described?
What is the current behaviour e.g., is it detecting out of range integers as in range too OR are in range integers being detected as out of range?
Secondly, you start your question with "accept any positive integer", but from the code you only ant positive integers from 0 to 15 (inclusive)

Comment: @OzairKafray The cmd just stops the checking once it reaches a value that is not between 0-15, rather than continuing to loop and checking the other values within file.

Comment: The tag `cmd` seems to be misleading. Your question is specific to C++ and not command line or batch. Please consider removing that tag.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be trying to convert your current input String to a number. If it fails, then there are other symbols involved as digits only. See `atoi()` (characters to integer) in the stdlib. Check out this site for even more sources of help: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/
However, this would not cover all the cases you mentioned as "invalid" in your description.

Another approach could be matching your input against a regular expression (RegEx). Check this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ and try a web search for tutorials and examples if you want to go that way.